# Annotation symbols

Tags: writing, symbols

Let's say you were going to put 3 annotations all on one page. What are the 3 different symbols you would use if you weren't going to use numbers?

Comment: -1 General reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common convention is [asterisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) *, [dagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_%28typography%29) †, and double dagger ‡.

This is typography rather than English.

Comment: +1 (though I can rarely think of a reason not to use numbers).

Comment: +1 for the second sentence. @language hacker: The first one is common knowledge, though.

Comment: And the fourth one is what, pilcrow? ¶

Answer (score 2):

What Henry says; another convention uses `*`, `**`, and `***`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I should use Roman numbers instead because they are also symbols :D **I**, **II**, **III** .